# How to include a Scala compiler plugin from a local path?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm developing a Scala compiler plugin, and right now I have to go to the plugin project, run `sbt publishLocal`, come back to my project, and run `sbt clean compile`.

This is because I'm using `addCompilerPlugin(...)` in my build.sbt

I wonder if there's a way to refer the compiler plugin's local path, so that I can simply run `sbt compile`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how we can achieve it:

```
scalacOptions in Compile ++= {
  val jar = (Keys.`package` in (plugin, Compile)).value
  System.setProperty("sbt.paths.plugin.jar", jar.getAbsolutePath)

  val addPlugin = "-Xplugin:" + jar.getAbsolutePath
  // Thanks Jason for this cool idea (taken from https://github.com/retronym/boxer)
  // add plugin timestamp to compiler options to trigger recompile of
  // main after editing the plugin. (Otherwise a 'clean' is needed in the current project)
  val dummy = "-Jdummy=" + jar.lastModified
  Seq(addPlugin, dummy)
}
```

Here's an example: https://github.com/GIVESocialMovement/scala-named-argument-compiler-plugin/blob/master/test-project/build.sbt#L26

This above runs `package` on the plugin project, gets its jar, and adds the plugin through `scalacOptions` on the current project.

Thanks this redditor for answering my question: https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/aq2bt6/just_made_a_compiler_plugin_to_enforce_named/